# Which package contains IWebHostEnvironment in .NET 8 so that I can use it in a non-web project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I am upgrading an existing net6 solution to net8. The entry project is a web api (`Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`) but some of the classes in the non-web projects (`Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"`) are injecting `IWebHostEnvironment`.

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment?view=aspnetcore-8.0) the interface lives in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` which I believe is an internal .NET package (well, package install says `The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 8.0.0 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project.`)

We used to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` package which contains the interface but the package is deprecated.

Comment: Check out suggested duplicate. You need to add FrameworkReference with value of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to use ASP.NET Core parts in library project. No separate Nugets are exposed anymore (since .NET Core 3 as far as I remember).